# ModRewrite redirect dynamic sub-domains

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve the following :

when user is trying to access "user1.domain.com"

I'd like to redirect to  : "user1.anotherdomain.com"

I've tried this rule, but that didn't work

RewriteRule ^(.*).domain.com$ $1.anotherdomain.com [R=301,NC]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this ought to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1.anotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```